# Molecule fingerprint MorganConnectivity

Tags: chemistry, resourcefunction

I am looking for a way to calculate the MorganConnectivity finger print for molecule object in Mathematica. v12.1 seemed to have an undocumented function MoleculeFingerprint

```
 Chemistry`MoleculeFingerprint[mol, FingerprintType -> "MorganConnectivity"]
```

where, mol is some Molecule object. However, when I try this on v13.0.1,the function returns without any output. [MoleculeSimilarityFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MoleculeFingerprintSimilarity) in function repository computes this fingerprint to compare two molecules. Is there a way to extract that fingerprint using some other function?

Thank you,

Comment: See the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262820/9490) - in version 13 you can use ```Chemistry`ExtendedConnectivityFingerprint``` to obtain the fingerprint directly

Comment: Thank you! I notice that on the linked question you mentioned a cloud notebook documenting some of these functions and use cases. I guess I would like to send a gentle reminder and much appreciation for that effort. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The molecule fingerprint functions have been compiled into a paclet and placed in the new [Wolfram Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/), with extensive documentation.  In the [Molecule Fingerprints](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframChemistry/MoleculeFingerprints/) paclet there are functions for creating atom pair fingerprints, topological fingerprints (a.k.a. RDKit fingprints or Daylight fingerprints), extended connectivity fingerprints, and more.

In Mathematica version 13 or greater you can run

```
PacletInstall["WolframChemistry/MoleculeFingerprints"]
```

which should return a `PacletObject` to indicate successful installation. To see the available functions use

```
Needs["WolframChemistry`MoleculeFingerprints`"]

?WolframChemistry`MoleculeFingerprints`*
```

[image]

Clicking any of the symbols brings up the documentation page.  To get a fingerprint using non-default options use something like

```
m = Molecule["CCC(=O)Oc1ccc2c(c1)CC[C@@H]1[C@@H]2CC[C@]2([C@H]1C[C@H]([C@@H]2OC(=O)CC)O)C"];
In[9]:= TopologicalFingerprint[m, "SparseArray", 
  "CountSimulation" -> True] // OutputForm

Out[9]//OutputForm= SparseArray[<886>, {2048}]
```